# Is there a way to remove the pattern directive?

Tags: angular

Im using the "pattern" attribute in an input, but it gets assigned as a directive from the patternValidator that is defined on "@angular/forms"

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="imcFormGroup">
  <input #w type="text" inputmode="numeric" pattern="([0-9]{3}) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" placeholder="Weight" formControlName="weight">
</form>
```

I need to block the "pattern" directive inside "@angular/forms" so it doesn't get assigned into the FormControl as a validator.

Comment: does this pattern cause the validator to fail in some way?

Comment: Ye why is it bothering you anyway?

Comment: Im using a [mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-text-mask), and the input has to be **type="text"**, then to show the numeric keyboard on iOS i need to add the pattern attribute, so when i use a mask like **([0-9]{3}) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}** to show on the input ** (0000) 0__-____ **, then this makes the pattern validator "invalid" because of the parentheses and the lines

Comment: You could just remove that validator after form is initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should work if you add the pattern with `[attr.pattern]="'([0-9]{3}) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}'"`

see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8eahic